# Referencing to an associative array value from PDO::FETCH_ASSOC

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Im having a very basic problem using PDO and i need some help - chances are I have a syntax error somewhere but i cant for the life of me find it (im new to PDO and havent used associative arrays very much so focus on this part of the code!)

I am selecting all the data from my database associated with a user with a certain email address using the following code:

```
$id = 'email@address.com';


$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM first_page WHERE email=?');
$stmt->bindValue(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$resulty = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

print_r($resulty);
echo $resulty['title'];
```

the `print_r` displays the associative array in its entirety, but the `echo` doesnt show the stored value for the column 'title'. There *is* a column called 'title' in the database, so im presuming im referencing it incorrectly. However it looks near identical to an example I have in a book in front of me so I dont know where to start looking!

The print_r output is:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [user_id] => 93 [time_stamp] => 2014-03-04 22:00:16 [title] => Mr [first_name] => Pete [surname] => John [phone] => 2147483647 [email] => email@address.com))
```

Comment: Post the results of print_r($resulty); or at least a relevant chunk of it.

Comment: `echo $resulty[0]['title'];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$stmt->fetchAll()` returns an array of associative arrays, because it supports returning more than one row worth of data.

Even if your result set has one row, `fetchAll()` still returns an array of one element, which is the associative array for the one row.

So you need:

```
echo $resulty[0]['title'];
```

Comment: After adding the edit to the question I presumed it was something to do with the array in an array! Is there an alternative to using fetchAll so I can reference to it like I have done?

Comment: Sure, you could use `while ($resulty = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) ...` to get one row at a time.

Comment: I will only ever be retrieving one row (the email address is unique) so I presume I just use your code above but drop the 'while'? (ie replace fetchAll with fetch?)

Comment: I dont think I needed to ask that - it is very obvious once I read it back that it is the correct thing to do!! :)

Answer (score 1):

In order to scale this up - i.e. if you have more than a single result, you can use a foreach loop with the array $resulty. This eliminates the need to use $resulty[0], $resulty[1], etc.

```
foreach ($resulty as $result){
    echo $result['title'];
}
```

Comment: I should never have more than one result (it is the data refering to the one user with a unique email address and Im trying to retrieve the data for this user so I can pre-populate a form) so can I use an alternative to fetchAll so I dont need to use the foreach loop?

Comment: You could just use fetch. That returns one row at a time. You could also add LIMIT 1 at the end of your query. But I believe the resulting array will have the same structure. You'll probably still have to use the [0] notation.